# How would I solve this modular arithmetic? (large number)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve this modular arithmetic problem but the numbers are large. How would I simplify?

$M \equiv (1567)^{5}$ mod $2881$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If there were 4 digits in the exponent also then you could say that the numbers are large. IIRC products of two natural numbers $<3000$ are handled precisely by modern pocket calculators, so I fail to see a problem here. Calculate the remainders of $1567^2$, square that to find the remainder of $1567^4$, multiply by $1567$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You could start from $M \equiv (1567)^{5}$ mod $2881 \iff \begin{cases} M \equiv (1567)^{5} \mbox{mod} (43) \\ M \equiv (1567)^{5} \mbox{mod} (67)\end{cases}$

Try to reduce $1567$ mod $43$ and $67$, find a solution than combine them to get the solution mod $2881$.

Comment: How would I combine them?

Comment: Using [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)